# Does the sweep line Algorithm produce a maximum independent set?

Tags: graph-theory

We know that  a **sweep line algorithm** or plane sweep algorithm is a type of algorithm that uses a conceptual sweep line or sweep surface to solve various problems in Euclidean space  [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm)

Sweep lines used in interval graphs **IG** to find intersection between intervals. These intersections transformed later on into independent sets. 
In addition, **Sweep Line algorithm** produces a **maximal independent set** **IS** of intervals.

But is the **maximal IS**  = **maximum IS** of the interval graph?

Please look at the graph : 
By using Sweep Line Algorithm I find there is a maximal **IS** with 2,
if it is  maximal :
but how can I show this **|IS|** is also maximum at same time ? / or not ?!

[image]

Comment: Is |IS| a maximum also ?

Comment: I think we need details on how the sweep proceeds on interval graphs.  Does it start from the left, and add intervals greedily whenever they can fit ?

Comment: it start from left to right, yes

Comment: Then I guess you can check that on the intervals $(1, 10), (2, 3), (5, 6)$, greedily adding $(1, 10)$ first will yield a maximal but not maximum indset.